# Bad formatting on react-native's webview when device has bigger font size

Tags: android, reactjs, webview, react-native

When rendering a webpage on Android Devices using react-native webview with a system's text font size bigger than default, the webview displays a bigger font as expected, although it **"hides"** some of the text. The end of the line is hidden and no scroll option appears, so the text becomes incomplete.

I already tried to set `scrollEnabled` and `scalesPageToFit` but it doesn't seem to work.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Did you get any positive results?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am still facing the issue